# Tokenize giving opposite of expected results

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm trying to use the tokenize function to extract the numeric values from a string.

```
tokenize(X:37381.56_Y:2478.73_Z:3747.87,'\d{3,}.\d{0,}')
```

yields

```
'X:','_Y:','_Z:'
```

instead of the desired coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're using the coordinates as the tokens in the pattern. Try using characters other than what's in the coordinates.

Example:

```
tokenize('X:37381.56_Y:2478.73_Z:3747.87','[^\d\.]+')
```

produces:

```
37381.56 2478.73 3747.87
```